# C# 1024bit encryption gone wrong

Tags: c#, encryption

i am using this code to encrypt bytes, i have tested it from 1-255 bytes, and every byte with value larger than 128 becomes decrypted as 63

[image]

```
AEK is a 16char string
public byte[] AE1024(byte[] __test)
    {
        byte[] data = __test;
        byte[] rgbKey = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AEK.Substring(0, AEK.Length / 2));
        byte[] rgbIV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AEK.Substring(AEK.Length / 2, AEK.Length / 2));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(1024);
        DESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, desCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] result = new byte[(int)memoryStream.Position];
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        memoryStream.Read(result, 0, result.Length);
        cryptoStream.Close();
        memoryStream.Dispose();
        return result;
    }
```

And here is the decrypt method

```
public byte[] AD1024(byte[] __test)
    {
        byte[] data =__test;
        byte[] rgbKey = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AEK.Substring(0, AEK.Length / 2));
        byte[] rgbIV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AEK.Substring(AEK.Length / 2, AEK.Length / 2));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data.Length+1);
        DESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        ICryptoTransform x = desCryptoServiceProvider.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, x, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        memoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        string decrypted = new StreamReader(cryptoStream).ReadToEnd();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        memoryStream.Dispose();
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decrypted);
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?  And why ASCII?

Comment: The question is how can i fix it so the bytes with value higher than 128 wont become 63.

Comment: Why *are* there bytes that are > 128? Normal characters are all below 128. Probably decryption totally failed and the output is random.

Comment: Btw, the crypto that you have there is garbage. If you want to achieve actual security I recommend you use some higher-level primitives from trusted sources. I can spot many problems with this code and it is highly non-trivial to create working crypto code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing 63 is that you are using ASCII encoding.  Any integer over 128 will become 63 (or ?) when encoding:

```
static void Main()
{
    byte[] bytes = new[]{(byte)129};

    string asciiString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

    byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(asciiString);

    Console.WriteLine(bytes[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(asciiString);
    Console.WriteLine(encodedBytes[0]);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The above outputs:

```
129
?
63
```

Since bytes > 128 do not correspond to text in ASCII or Unicode, I would suggest as @usr says in the comments that your encryption/decryption routines are broken.

Comment: Which encoding should i use for 1-255 integrers?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry my fault.  I've updated again.  However, the console output that you have posted does not seem to be actual text, so maybe your test is broken. :)

Answer (score 0):

your decryption method is ... creative ...

why do you use a stream reader? your original encrypted data was byte[] ... not string ...

get a decryptor

make a new MemoryStream

wrap it into a new CryptoStream with CryptoStreamMode.Write, using the decryptor as ICryptoTransform

write your encrypted bytes into the CryptoStream

get your hands on the MemoryStreams Buffer which will hold your clear text byte array